# Visual Studio 2012 Linker Directory - Using Macros

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, macros, linker

I've come across a strange problem with Visual Studio 2012, and was hoping somebody could shed some light.

I have several projects in one solution, one of which is a library which builds a .lib file.
All of the projects are set to use the same output directory (relative to the solution directory).
For one of the projects which uses the library, I want to set the output directory as one of the linker directories, so it can find the .lib file.

So, in `Project Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories`, I added `$(OutDir)`. So my whole string looks like `$(OutDir);$(LibraryPath)`.
However, during build I get a linker error saying that my .lib cannot be opened.

Strangely, though, I have used this exact same setting for a *different project* in the *same solution*, which uses the same library, and builds fine.

To check that I hadn't set the Output Directory setting incorrectly, I copied it and pasted that into the Library Directories, and it works fine.

Anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Did you set up the build order properly, by specifying a dependency between the library client and the project producing the library?

Comment: Yeah, the dependencies are set correctly, with the project depending on the library. I've also tried adding the _other_ project that uses the library as a dependency, in case it was a problem with them both trying to access the .lib file, and that made no difference either.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you actually enter the `;`? In case you did, remove it and place the macros on separate lines. When you enter the macros through the GUI, does it display the expected directories? Have you inspected the directory to see whether or not the .lib file is there?

Comment: No, the semicolon was automatically added by Visual Studio. I used the little GUI editor that opens (where you can browse for a folder). The same set up worked with a different project in the _same solution_.